# Use Volume Shadow Copy from Delphi with WMI Class Win32_ShadowCopy

Tags: delphi, wmi, volume-shadow-service

Does anyone have any pointers to using the WMI class Win32_Shadowcopy to create a temporary ("Backup") shanshot of a volume, in Delphi?

I have seen a generated unit (http://delphi-wmi-class-generator.googlecode.com/svn-history/r36/trunk/root_CIMV2/uWin32_ShadowCopy.pas), but I'm not sure how to do the actual calls to:

- create the snapshot
- get a reference to the generated volume id
- work with the files in the generated volume
- release the snapshot when I'm done.

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Mark